# How to fix 'No rule to make target `project-name'. Stop.'

Tags: qt

I'm trying to build my qt project after macOS 10.15 Catalina update. Always get en error:
`:-1: error: No rule to make target 'AircraftAlgorithmPack'.  Stop.`

And recommendations:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'AircraftAlgorithmPack'.  Stop.
The platform SDK has been changed from version 10.14 to version 10.15.
This requires a fresh build. Please wipe the build directory completely,
including any .qmake.stash and .qmake.cache files generated by qmake.
/Users/arseniyspiridonov/Qt/5.13.1/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/sdk.mk:22: *** ^.  Stop.
19:01:49: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project AircraftAlgorithmPack (kit: Desktop Qt 5.13.1 clang 64bit)
When executing step "qmake"
```

I've already checked that my SDK version is 10.15.
I've tried to clean project, to delete build directory, to rerun qmake,  to make context change in make file (from 10.14 to 10.15), to write some mantras not to check SDK version. All advices from google.
Nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to erase all .qmake.stash files - they might also be located in your project's folder. Completely delete your build directory. The .qmake.stash files are hidden from Finder, so you might need to use the command shell to locate them.

Comment: All .qmake.stash files are deleted from MacBook

Comment: Hi, I got the same issue did you find a solution?

Comment: Unbelievable! How does this error still exist in Qt5, let alone the latest Qt 6? Even Qt Creator doesn't correct it with Clean Project.